# SQP and first order Taylor approximation

Tags: calculus, optimization, taylor-expansion, quadratic-programming, linearization

I am trying to use the SQP solver with a nonlinear constraint. The solver requires a linear constraint so I am trying to approximate the constraint with the first-order Taylor approximation. Is this to correct way how to use SQP solvers or is this either a completely wrong or naive approach?

Problem formulation
$$\min_{x} \quad  x^2 \\ 
\textrm{s.t.} \quad  g(x): \cos{(x)} \geq 0.7 \\$$

SQP solver formulation
$$\min_{x} \quad  xPx \\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad  l \leq Ax \leq u\\$$

1st order Taylor around of nonlinear constraint $g(x)$
$$g(x): \quad \cos{(x)}\geq 0.7 \\
\textrm{1st order Taylor around }x_0\textrm{:} \quad g(x_0) + \frac{\partial g(x_0)}{\partial x_0}(x-x_0) \geq 0.7 \\
 \quad g(x_0) + \frac{\partial g(x_0)}{\partial x_0}x - \frac{\partial g(x_0)}{\partial x_0}x_0  \geq 0.7 \\$$

Expressing $l$ bound and $A$ matrix for SQP solver:
$$
0.7  \leq g(x_0) + \frac{\partial g(x_0)}{\partial x_0}x - \frac{\partial g(x_0)}{\partial x_0}x_0  \\
0.7  - g(x_0) + \frac{\partial g(x_0)}{\partial x_0}x_0 \leq \frac{\partial g(x_0)}{\partial x_0}x \\
l = 0.7  - g(x_0) + \frac{\partial g(x_0)}{\partial x_0}x_0\\
A = \frac{\partial g(x_0)}{\partial x_0}\\
l \leq Ax
$$

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking. SQP describes a large class of algorithms. The basic idea is solving the subproblem consisting of a quadrative cost approximation and linear constraint approximation, but practical SQP algorithms are much more complex.

Comment: @copper.hat I am asking if this is the right way how to transform the NLP into QP formalism. I am planning to use SQP so after solving the current subproblem, I want to approximate the constraint with the Taylor approximation around the subproblem solution.

Comment: Yes, I got that. What I am saying is that applying SQP in practice involves many more considerations than just forming the 2nd/1st order Taylor approximations and iterating.